# How to fix hose bib?

Tags: plumbing, leak, hose

I have four hoses at my house and they all failed over the winter and started flooding the house. I'm going to fix them one at a time.

I've unscrewed the first one and pulled out this:

[image]

I expected this piece to have a hole in it, but it seems solid. I don't have the slightest clue by what principle it opens and closes the flow of water.

I then cut a hole in the ceiling and found this:

[image]

The brick is about 2 feet away so I'm not really able to reach it. I would appreciate any advice on the steps I should take to fix this problem.

Edit: to answer the questions asked in the comments:

The hose was not attached. I live in Philadelphia and I believe it got below freezing, There is no insulation in that crawl space. There is no rupture in the stem. I'm not even sure where the water was coming from but I'll investigate by carefully turning the water on.

UPDATE: [Video of the leak](https://youtu.be/abs2-uz3JwM).

UPDATE 2: Managed to disconnect the pex and pull out the assembly. The following is a picture of the rupture. To me, it looks like they used type M copper, doesn't it? I thought that M was against code.

[image]

Comment: When the hose bib failed, was there a hose attached to the faucet? How cold does it get in your area? Did you remove any insulation to get the second picture? If there is no rupture in the pipe that is evident from the hole in the ceiling, the stem of the hose bib may have been the part that failed. I presume before you took it apart, if the water was on that water would be raining down still?

Comment: Did you leave the hoses attached to them over the winter?  Do the hoses have valves or closeable nozzles on them?

Comment: Take that valve stem to your local plumbing supply house (go to a big-box store as a desperation, last ditch measure only). They'll take one look at it and know what's wrong  and be able to get you the right part. Will probably be cheaper than the big box, too.

Comment: The stem that is in the picture will not be the part that caused the leak, it will be the housing it goes into will be the damaged part, if things happened the way I suspect. I need answers from the OP on the questions earlier....

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've just added a video of the leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at a sillcock. The piece you removed goes into a larger pipe and the actual valve is at the end of the pipe, inside the house. When you turn on the water, the valve at the end opens up and water flows through the pipe and out.

You should be able to remove and replace the entire assembly simply by turning the outside spigot counterclockwise and getting one the same size. You might be able to get replacement parts from a plumbing supply store.

The below picture illustrates a normal spigot and then a sillcock installation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Here's the video to the leak: https://youtu.be/abs2-uz3JwM Does seeing that change the proposed strategy?

Comment: @Wynne According to that video, the outer pipe has cracked so the entire sillcock will have to be replaced. It's strange it would fail there if the water was able to drain out when the valve was closed.  When removing it from the outside, have someone inside watching the pipe to make sure only the sillcock is turning and not the whole pipe.

Comment: Thanks! And by "pipe" on the inside you mean the pex tubing?

Comment: @Wynne  Yes, I wasn't sure what it was.  Can you find the other end of the pex?  It could be tricky undoing that connection. You might have to reach in there with a wrench and grab the pex fitting while someone else turns the sillcock from the outside.  You could also cut the plex toward the ceiling opening and pull the sillcock and pex out... but not sure if fitting will go through opening in brick.

Comment: @Wynne  Did you replace it?

Comment: Not yet. Will definitely report back.

Comment: Updated the post. Was able to pull out the assembly and find the rupture.

Answer (score 1):

That is called a Frost-Proof Sillcock.
The part you removed is the valve stem.  The end of that is the actual valve that opens to control the water.  The seat is designed to be inside your basement so as to less likely to freeze in the winter.

That also means that it is connected to your indoor plumbing at the brass connector I see in your second picture.  Whoever installed it, must have been able to reach it.

If it's not leaking on the inside, then you may be able to just replace the valve "washer" (that conical thing on the end of the stem) and/or packing.  You could try taking it to a plumbing supply and see if they have a compatible seal.

If you google this term you'll find a couple videos showing how to install them.